# Expressing data in one row instead of several

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a function that returns this table

```
Firstname Lastname  c1  c2  c3  c4
Förnamn Efternamn   DIG187/1    NULL    NULL    NULL
Förnamn Efternamn   DIG281/2    NULL    NULL    NULL
Förnamn Efternamn   DIG281/4    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

How can I make it so it returns

```
Firstname Lastname  c1  c2  c3  c4
Förnamn Efternamn   DIG187/1    DIG281/2    DIG281/4    NULL
```

Function

```
Declare @FirstName nvarchar(50) = 'Förnamn'
Declare @LastName nvarchar(50) = 'Efternamn'

INSERT INTO @table(FirstName,Lastname,c1) 
SELECT @FirstName,@LastName,CONCAT(Kurs, '/', Period)
FROM getFourCoursesByYear(@year)
```

Comment: Is it possible more than 4 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered many times. If you want to do it using simple sql, you can do it using aggregation together with `case when`

```
INSERT INTO @table(FirstName,Lastname,c1,c2,c3,c4) 
SELECT 
  @FirstName,@LastName,
  max(case when Period = 1 then CONCAT(Kurs, '/', Period) else null end) as c1,
  max(case when Period = 2 then CONCAT(Kurs, '/', Period) else null end) as c2,
  max(case when Period = 3 then CONCAT(Kurs, '/', Period) else null end) as c3,
  max(case when Period = 4 then CONCAT(Kurs, '/', Period) else null end) as c4
FROM getFourCoursesByYear(@year)
```

Remark that it's not needed the use of `GROUP BY` because `@Firstname` and `@Lastname` are immutable variables at query execution time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to study max(case when...) further. Haven't used it before.

Comment: You can try removing `MAX`, you will se many rows creating kind of ladder. With `MAX`, you group the information, resulting in just one single row.

Comment: @HannesElfving . . . This does not do what you specify, because `c3` will be `NULL` and `c4` will have a value.